# Factorization of $a^{n}-b^{n}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, binomial-theorem

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $A, B$ be two bounded linear operators on $X$ such that $AB \neq BA$. Can we write $A^{n}-B^{n}$ as follows and what is the expression of $K$:
$$A^{n}-B^{n}=C(A-B)+K(AB-BA).$$
Where $C=A^{n-1}+BA^{n-2}+\dots+B^{n-1}$ and $K \in \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$.

Comment: You can write $$ A^n-B^n = \sum_{r+s=n-1} A^r (A-B) B^s. $$

Comment: Please Mr@runway44, see the proof of Theorem 1, assertion (k) in  "Zivkovic, S.: Semi-Fredholm operators and perturbation. Publ. Inst. Math.
Beo. 61, 73–89 (1997)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n=3$, $$A^3-B^3-(A^2+BA+B^2)(A-B)=A^2B+BAB-BA^2-B^2A$$

And you can't reasonably expect this to be a scalar multiple of $AB-BA$: there must be counterexamples with $\dim X=3$. I would guess you can make do with $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&2&0\\0&0&3\end{pmatrix}$, $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Mr. Gaz. S. If we have $A^{n}-B^{n}$ is Fredholm operator on $X$, what about the factorization?.

Comment: @Med If $\dim X$ is finite, then all endomorphisms are Fredholm.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Gae. S.

Comment: Please. Can you see the proof of Theorem 1 assertion (K) page 5/17 "  Živković, S.: Semi-Fredholm operators and perturbation. Publ. Inst. Math.
Beo. 61, 73–89 (1997)  ".

Comment: @Med No, I can't.

Comment: Mr@gae. S. We can write $A^{3}-B^{3}-(A^{2}+BA+B^{2})=(A+B)(AB-BA)-(BA-AB)A$ .

Comment: @Med I can agree with $$A^3-B^3-(A^2+BA+B^2)(A-B)=(A+B)(AB-BA)+(AB-BA)A$$

Comment: Sorry Mr@Gae. S. Yes, I just forgot to write the factor $A-B$.

Comment: Mr@Gae. S. Can we write  $AB^{2}-BA^{2}$  according to $AB-BA$? and thanks.